# Apple Push Certificates Expiration

Tags: ios, service, apple-push-notifications

Today I got an email from appleid@id.apple.com saying that our Apple Push Service Certificate is about to expire.
I haven't seen any email from Apple like this. Wanted to see if it is legit?

> Dear ***,
>
> The following Apple Push Notification Service certificate, created for
>   AppleID [email address] will expire on April 11, 2018. Revoking or
>   allowing this certificate to expire will require existing devices to
>   be re-enrolled with a new push certificate.
>
> Mobile Device Management - null
>
> Please contact your vendor to generate a new request (a signed CSR),
>   then visit https://identity.apple.com/pushcert to renew your Apple
>   Push Notification Service certificate.
>
> Thank You,
>
> Apple Push Notification Service

Comment: So I contacted Apple and they said it's definitely a phishing attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I received this email as well and our application does not support APNS so it must be a phishing attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://developer.apple.com/account/ and tap **Certificates, IDs & Profiles** and you will see which certificates need your attention.

Comment: I got a lot of apps up there and haven't received any email like that from Apple before. This looks like a phishing email but I am not sure? "Mobile Device Management - null". I haven't had that MDM set up btw

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8062560 suggests fake and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3932943 suggests real... I'd call Apple directly

Comment: thanks. I found that topic earlier today. Couldn't get more info on that :/